# Parsing XML file for speed or something else? ASP.NET MVC scheduled job and data updating

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc

I am building an ASP.NET MVC application.
It will parse an xml file from an other website every 15 secs using Quartz. I will then use HTML agility pack to parse the xml and put the data I would like into 2 DataTables. Is it a better solution to:

1. Download and copy the XML file into App Data folder. Put the code of parsing the XML and populating Datatables in the controller of a partial view which is called by an other View? Each visitor of this view will renew the partial view content by jQuery every 15 secs. But then, there will be too many parsings of the XML file if many users use this View.
2. Download the XML file in a class in Model. Parse with HTML agility pack. Create the DataTables there, BUT how could I pass the datatables to the partial View? And how the View will be fetch the datatables data every 15 secs? ( I have already tried this, used an Ijob to get the XML file, put the data into the DataTables but now, How could I use the content of the datatables in the Controller(Partial View)

Which is the better way to make the partial View put the data into DataTables, and update the data in the View every 15 secs without problems?

Comment: hit the db? what do you mean by that? I do not know nodeJS but I am willing to learn how to use it for this task...Is there any tutorial for this?

Comment: by the way, the XML file contains info that are updated every 15 secs, that's why I am using Quartz to download it every 15 secs... 
No, I do not use a database, I use DataTables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the OutputCache functionality. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

You could have your view make an ajax call to the controller every 15 seconds, caching the parsed object for reuse by other users.